# Scrolling background image in ViewPager?

Tags: java, android

I am looking if there are any ways to implement background image scrolling with ViewPager. What I want to achieve is shown on following [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=2UnydjgfonA#t=35s).

I've researched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775650/android-moving-background-image-while-navigating-through-views), but it works kinda buggy (it also uses own ViewPager implementation).

Thank everyone in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14713965/347565).

I don't think there is any way you can do it without extending ViewPager, the original implementation does not support this kind of feature.

Comment: Thank you, it has worked! There were some issues so I had fix them manually, but now everything is awesome!

Comment: I am still working on it too (like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715435/overriding-ondraw-for-viewpager-sometimes-gives-black-screen/14716799) and there is still some problem when the pages in the ViewPager change. If you fix some problems, I hope you can push them to that GitHub...

Comment: I've posted my version of ViewPagerParallax to [pastebin.com/AgqBb8pW](http://pastebin.com/AgqBb8pW). I've got rid of magic numbers like 4 and 5 that were in your version, and added the support of background images of any size.

Comment: I had made some other fix (using getScrollX instead of some black magic), otherwise it would run into problems when inserting pages "in the middle" of the adapter.... I just merged your changes in. Thanks!

Comment: You could add me to a contributors list, so I can push my further improvements (if any). [Me on github](https://github.com/bmaslakov)